# Displaying the alert in the main view of the function from another file

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have this code:

MainViewControler:

```
func errorLoginMessage(txt: String, title: String){
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: txt, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok".localized(), style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            exit(0)
        }))
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

and files in function AppSystem.swift:

```
func startUpdate(){ 
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
        dispatchGroup.enter()

        let cms = ServerConnect()
        cms.getJsonProducts(completion: { (data) in
            switch data {
            case .succes(let data):
                self.saveJsonFileToTheDiskProducts(downloadData: data)
            case .error(let error):
                self.errorLoginMessage(txt: "MainView - Error 101: Configuration files can not be created. \(error)", title: "Blad".localized())
                print("")
                break
            }
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        })
    }
```

I have error with this:

```
self.errorLoginMessage(txt: "MainView - Error 101: Configuration files can not be created. \(error)", title: "Blad".localized())
```

: Value of type 'AppSystem' has no member 'errorLoginMessage'

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: you need to call `errorLoginMessage` inside the appsystem page else follow the Sharad Chauhan answer

Answer (score 0):

As alert is not part of your `AppSystem` class, you need to pass a message to `MainViewController` to show a message if there is a failure.

You can use `Delegates`, `Notifiations` or `Completion blocks`, this is an example of `completion block` :

```
func startUpdate(completion:@escaping(Bool)->()){
     // No need of DispatchGroup as pointed by Anbu.Karthik, as with completion block you are making this function work asynchronously only.
    //let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    //dispatchGroup.enter()

    let cms = ServerConnect()
    cms.getJsonProducts(completion: { (data) in
        switch data {
        case .succes(let data):
            self.saveJsonFileToTheDiskProducts(downloadData: data)
            completion(true)
        case .error(let error):
            completion(false)
            //self.errorLoginMessage(txt: "MainView - Error 101: Configuration files can not be created. \(error)", title: "Blad".localized())
            print("")
            break
        }
        //dispatchGroup.leave()
    })
}
```

Call it like this in `MainViewController` :

```
startUpdate { (success) in
    if !success {
        //Show alert
        self.errorLoginMessage(txt: "MainView - Error 101: Configuration files can not be created. \(error)", title: "Blad".localized())
    }
}
```

Comment: in here what is the use of `DispatchGroup`, its only enough `completion:@escaping(Bool)`

Comment: you only added the   `let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()`, you need to tell the   purpose of  `let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()` in your code